Can I put a generator expression inside a set command in CMake?
When I build SDL (Simple Direct Media Layer) it has an option to build with address sanitizer using the variable you can set SDL_ASAN. I'm pretty sure within its CMake files it sets things depending on whether this variable is set. I want the address sanitizer to be used in Debug mode. Now, if I'm using a single generator solution I can do:
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUALS "Debug")
set(SDL_ASAN TRUE)
endif()

However in multi-generator systems like Visual Studio the BUILD_TYPE can't be checked at configure time, so you need a generator expression:
set(SDL_ASAN $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:TRUE>)

The problem with this (it seems), is that when I do something like:
add_subdirectory(${SDL_SOURCE_DIR})

It calls the SDL CMakeLists and then somewhere in there is something like:
if (SDL_ASAN)
#SOMETHING
endif()

However I don't think this is sufficient to do anything meaningful because the generator expression sets the variable after, at build time, which is too late. In these circumstances how can I get SDL to use SDL_ASAN in Debug mode and not Release mode for a multi-generator system like Visual Studio?

"In these circumstances how can I get SDL to use SDL_ASAN in Debug mode and not Release mode for a multi-generator system like Visual Studio?" - You will be able to do that when SDL developers rewrite the logic dependent from SDL_ASAN into generator expressions. Currently SDL code contains plain if (SDL_ASAN), as you have already guessed: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt#L3074. The whole purpose of multi-configuration generators is to execute CMake code once for all build types. Obviously, that execution cannot enter if branch and skip it at the same time.

"Can I put a generator expression inside a set command in CMake?" - Yes, you can. But such variable will just contain that expression unmodified, as a string. So, whenever one will dereference the variable, it will be expanded into that string. Whether such string will be interpreted as a generator expression or not depends on its usage. CMake documentation explicitly notes, when a command's argument will be interpreted as generator expression. Arguments for if command are not interpreted in the such way.
